# Webpack CopyPlugin : add file to plugin directory

Tags: npm, webpack, compilation

I'd like to add the current module folder during my webpack compilation to my dist/ directory. For now, in /dist, I have something like that

```
const toCopy = [
  './../../../../node_modules/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.js',
  './../../../../node_modules/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css',
]
```

this is the part of my webpack CopyPlugin

```
...
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: toCopy.map((entry) => {
        console.log(entry);
        return { from: entry }
      })
    })
  ]
```

And it gives me that

```
/dist
  flatpickr.min.css
  flatpickr.min.css
```

And I'd like that in order to avoid conflict if files from different modules have the same name .

for example, flatpickr as a `ie.css, fr.js`... but some other module could also have those files

```
/dist
 /flatpickr
     flatpickr.min.css
     flatpickr.min.css
```

Answer (score 0):

I've ended by created a loop over all my assets to copy to keep the CopyPlugin structure

```
const toCopy = new Map();
toCopy.set('popper', './../../contrib/bootstrap_sass/js/popper.min.js',);
toCopy.set('flatpickr', ['./../../../../node_modules/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.js',
  './../../../../node_modules/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css']);

let toCopyFormatted = [];
for (let [dest, entries] of toCopy.entries()) {
  if (typeof entries === 'string') {
    let data = {to: dest}
    data['from'] = entries;
    toCopyFormatted.push(data);
  } else {
    entries.forEach(function (v, k) {
      let data = {to: dest}
      data['from'] = v;
      toCopyFormatted.push(data);
    })
  }
}
```